# reading a json object in jsp

Tags: javascript, json, jsp, object, parsing

i have a JSON object passed to the jsp page. it is passed as a string. now i have to parse this string and retrieve the values that are passed through the JSON object.  so that i can print the values in the same jsp.

Answer (score 1):

There's lots of resources, including libraries & plugins for various technologies/frameworks on [json.org](http://www.json.org/).

Answer (score 1):

With tons of JSON parsers, it comes down to how you want to deal with data in JSON. My personal favorite from the lot is [Jackson](http://jackson.codehaus.org/Tutorial), but many others work well for simple cases too, including the "reference implementation" (aka [JSON.org parser](http://json.org/java)).

(I assume you want a Java parser, given reference to jsp)

Answer (score 0):

My preferred solution to this problem involves using a JSON parser that provides an output that implements the java.util.Map and java.util.List interface. This allows for simple parsing of the JSON structure in the JSP Expression language.

Here is an example using JSON4J provided with Apache Wink. The sample imports JSON data from a URL, parses it in a java scriptlet and browses the resulting structure.

```
<c:import var="dataJson" url="http://localhost/request.json"/>
<% 
String json = (String)pageContext.getAttribute("dataJson");
pageContext.setAttribute("parsedJSON", org.apache.commons.json.JSON.parse(json));
%>
Fetch the name of the node at index 1 : ${parsedJSON.node[1].name}
```

To make this clean, it would be preferable to create a JSTL tag to do the parsing and avoid java scriplet.

```
<c:import var="dataJson" url="http://localhost/request.json"/>
<json:parse json="${dataJson}" var="parsedJSON" />
Fetch the name of the node at index 1 : ${parsedJSON.node[1].name}
```